# android listview spinner when scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom **ListView** with **Spinner** that fill with a **ListArray**.

It works fine without **ListView Scroll**


But when I add some items to my custom **ListView** and I select one item of first or second on my **Spinner** and I scroll down my **ListView** (until that row disappear) I see another **Spinner** on bottom items will selected (like the upper)

My selection kept but another **Spinner** on bottom **ListView** be select


My code is :

```
   public class SoundListView extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        List<String> DataList;
        private final Activity context;
        private ViewGroup vg;
        int startTimer, stopTimer,rPosition;
        String fileTagName = "",externalTagFileName = "",tagFileName= "",fileName = "";

        public SoundListView (Activity context, ArrayList arrSubject, ArrayList arrDurationSplit, ArrayList ids,ArrayList arrFileName,ArrayList arrDuration,ArrayList arrIdTag,ArrayList arrTagName,ArrayList arrMainId,ArrayList arrStartTime, ArrayList arrStopTime) {
            super(context, R.layout.activity_list, arrSubject);
            this.context = context;
            this.arrSubject = arrSubject;
            this.arrDurationSplit = arrDurationSplit;
            this.arrIdTag = arrIdTag;
            this.arrDuration = arrDuration;
            this.arrTagName = arrTagName;
            this.arrMainId = arrMainId;
            this.arrStartTime = arrStartTime;
            this.arrStopTime = arrStopTime;
            this.arrFileName = arrFileName;
            this.ids = ids;
        }
        private ArrayList arrSubject = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList arrDurationSplit = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList ids = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList arrIdTag = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList arrTagName = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList arrMainId = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList arrStartTime = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList arrStopTime = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList arrDuration = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList arrFileName = new ArrayList();
        final private ArrayList<String> arrayTasPath = new ArrayList<String>();

        static class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imgPlaySound,imgShareList;
            TextView txtCaption,txtDynamicTimer,txtDurationSplit,txtTotalTimer,txtHiden;
            Spinner spTags;
            SeekBar seekBar1;
            LinearLayout linearSeek;
            int position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position,View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            vg = parent;
            final ArrayList arrTagNameTemp = new ArrayList();
            final ArrayList arrStartTimeTemp = new ArrayList();
            final ArrayList arrStopTimeTemp = new ArrayList();

            arrTagNameTemp.add("all");
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.position = position;
                viewHolder.txtCaption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCaption);
                viewHolder.txtDynamicTimer  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDynamicTimer);
                viewHolder.txtDurationSplit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTotalTimer);
                viewHolder.imgPlaySound = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlaySound);
                viewHolder.imgShareList = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgShareList);
                viewHolder.linearSeek = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearSeek);
                viewHolder.spTags = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spTags);
                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrTagNameTemp);
                viewHolder.spTags.setAdapter(adapter);
                viewHolder.spTags.setSelection(0);
                final int duration = Integer.valueOf(arrDuration.get(position).toString());
                for(int i = 0; i < arrMainId.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (Integer.valueOf(arrMainId.get(i).toString()) == Integer.valueOf(ids.get(position).toString()))
                    {
                        arrTagNameTemp.add(arrTagName.get(i));
                        arrStartTimeTemp.add(arrStartTime.get(i));
                        arrStopTimeTemp.add(arrStopTime.get(i));
                    }
                }
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.txtCaption.setText(arrSubject.get(position).toString());
            return convertView;
        }
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all just tell me why are you using that much arraylists, can't you just use a single one with custom data type. In that single array all your values will be associated to each other and it will easy to manage them.

The solution for your issue that I can suggest is to create a single ArrayList with custom data type including all your values of all arraylists given above. And don not initialize your Array in Adapter. Initialize and add values where you are setting Adapter (In your Activity). you have to add a parameter in your main array let's say "selectedValue", by default it will be "all" but when user will select some value you will update the value of item on that specific position.

And then in your getView method you will check the value of "selectedValue" for each item, if it is equals to "all" then you will set it otherwise you will set the value of "selectedValue" to your spinner. Just keep one thing in mind you have to set a value to spinner of each item in both if and else clause.